# Android studio is adding cached version on Android device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room

I deleted the app that android studio adds on the Android device. Afterwards, I rerun from Android studio but Android studio is adding some kind of a cached version on my Android device. I do make use of ROOM and Recyclerview when I run it's prefilled with the same old data.

How can I Android Studio's run install clean APK on my Android device?

When I make a new emulator and press run the Recyclerview isn't prefilled with old data and it's fine.

Comment: Do you have backup enabled? That could be the reason. You install the app -> Google restores the backed up data

Comment: @gpunto thanks that was it :)) You can add it as answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have backup enabled on your device, each time you reinstall the app Android will restore the backed-up data.
More info about Auto Backup [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html).